# Can't run Xcode project on device even I did deep clean and reinstall Xcode, always error with Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, keychain

Everything was doing well, running multiple projects on simulators and on my three test devices (iPhone 8, iPhone 8 plus, and this current iPhone 11 (iOS 11.3.1)) until just one moment, when started to shows up this error, when I'm trying to run project on device. On simulator, it still works well.

Went through many of adviced steps, StackOverflow answers and even I cleaned up everything related to the XCode (in that time I already updated XCode on 11.4): deleted *~/Library/Developer/* , *~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcodeand* ; reinstall it and now it still doesn't work.

This becomes really frustrating and I would really appreciate for someone's help, who already have faced this problem, and I hope had resolved this.

[image: Full stack trace]

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/MyiOS
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E94B4D8B-47A3-49BC-A6D7-22A5C1914A23/MyiOS.app/Frameworks/KeychainAccess.framework/KeychainAccess: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the debugger log instead of a link to a screenshot. It's always better if people don't have to follow links just to understand what you're asking. Adding the stack trace would help as well.

Comment: Good to know for future, tnx

Comment: No need to wait for the future -- you can edit your question to improve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks, it's strange to answer on your own question, but in case someone faced this, this works for me, as in the first sight this was hopeless example.

This is for all you who will be at some moment on iOS 11.3.1 - there's a great chance to get this.

All you have to do is, believe or not, just comment your Podfile line use_frameworks! and it works.

References and thanks to this post: 
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3051#issuecomment-580003683

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering your own question if you find an answer that works for you before someone else offers one. Come back after a little while and accept your own answer (unless there's a better one) so that this question doesn't stay on the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something went wrong with KeychainAccess. Perhaps try to run pod install again to update your KeychainAccess Pod. If that doesn't work, try to run pod deintegrate and then pod install again.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I found the way for this.